# How to end a thread after a few second

Tags: c#, multithreading

In c# I'm working on my Eye Tracking project, with a Windows Forms Application. For the eye tracking process, so far I have created everything needed - including creating heatmap of the eye tracking data - and I'm working on my interface now.

On my main form, there are 4 buttons "Start Stream" that starts the program which take coordinates of the eyes and adds the data do the database. "Stop Stream" which ends the previous process. "Clear Database" which clears everything in the database. And "Create Heatmap" which makes some operations on the data to create a heatmap.

Now I want to change something. By clicking start button, the program opens a new form with a picturebox on fullscreen, and user gazes on the picture that opened. But, since it is not too possible to stop the stream while gazing on a fullscreen, I want to make the process stop by itself after, let's say 10 seconds.

My code for starting stream is:

```
flag = true;

        StreamOnPictureForm newStreamForm = new StreamOnPictureForm();
        newStreamForm.Show();
```

//this form is just a basic form with a picturebox in the center.

```
        Stream.resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false); 
        Thread thread = new Thread(Stream.GazeStream);
        thread.Start();
```

//this is my main method for reading the eye movement, and adding them to the DB.

The flag is for understanding that the program is running.

And the I stop the process with my "Stop Stream" button:

```
if (flag == true)
        {
            Stream.resetEvent.Set();
        }
        flag = false;
```

Now what I want is, to stop the stream without clicking any button. When I try to calculate the time and then stopping the stream with a code like this:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan byNow;
        bool isActive = true;
        int x;

        while (isActive == true)
        {
            byNow = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);
            x = (int)byNow.TotalSeconds;
            if (x > 5) { isActive = false; }
        }

        Stream.resetEvent.Set();
```

It starts adding data do the DB for 5 seconds, but my picture shown up on the screen after that amount of time, and while the picture is finally shown on the screen, the program no longer takes the data from the user's eyes, which is not what I want to do.

How can I end my thread (stop taking&adding data after a few seconds, and close the picture) ? Can somebody help me please?

Comment: `Thread thread = new Thread` That's legacy code. You should not be doing that in modern versions of .NET . Take a look at the `Task` Class.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your question where the code that checks the time is located, but the way your are doing it (with the while loop), you are locking that thread for the duration. Instead, use a timer to periodically check if the 5 seconds have passed (store the initial time in a variable); that way you don't lock the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your form with a backgroundworker and a cancellation Token.
The form stays at top as long until you send a cancellation.

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    private CancellationToken token;

    public TestForm(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.token = ct;
        this.BringToFront();

        DoBackgroundWork();
    }

    private void DoBackgroundWork()
    {
        BackgroundWorker w = new BackgroundWorker();
        w.DoWork += w_DoWork;
        w.RunWorkerCompleted += w_RunWorkerCompleted;
        w.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void w_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void w_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
           // Form stays open
        }
    }
}

// your start class
public class TestClass
{
    public void ShowWindowUntilStop()
    {
        System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
        TestForm t = new TestForm(cts.Token);
        t.Show();

        // do some work

        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```